# How to extract a complex area from image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I want to cut this red area out of similar screenshots:

[image: Input 1]

I find approx contours and vertical lines. This approach sometimes does not work. I'd like to hear your suggestions.

Comment: Your approach sometimes does not work in which way? It's easier to optimize code if you know what to improve.

Comment: could you show us sample results. we can start from there, instead of starting form scratch